# boto3 ClientError: You are not subscribed to this service

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I want to read spot prices using boto3. And I add an user using IAMP aws and give him policy to use

- EC2 service
- action:
- DescribeSpotPriceHistory + StartInstances + StopInstances

And I configure the aws on my UBUNTU machine using **awscli**

When I run simple example to get spot prices, I have the following error:

> ClientError: An error occurred (OptInRequired) when calling the
>   DescribeSpotPriceHistory operation: You are not subscribed to this
>   service. Please go to http://aws.amazon.com to subscribe.

CODE:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)

prices=client.describe_spot_price_history(InstanceTypes=['m3.medium'],MaxResults=1,ProductDescriptions=['Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)'],AvailabilityZone='us-east-1')

print prices['SpotPriceHistory'][0]
```

Comment: This error occurs when you don't have a valid credit card registered in AWS / there is an issue with the credit card. Check with AWS support team to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two issues with the `describe_spot_price_history()` call you are making:

1. `AvailabilityZone='us-east-1'` is wrong. You must specify an AZ: `us-east-1a` or `us-east-1b` etc., not the region `us-east-1`. This gave me a `ClientError: ... InvalidParameterValue` when I tried.
2. Perhaps this is really what you intended, but note that with `MaxResults=1` you will really only get one data point back from the call, which might not be super useful. You would have to iterate through the remaining pages to get the rest of the price history. I am not sure if there is any explicit guarantee that the first result being retrieved is always the most-recent data point for this price history (especially since you are not specifying a `StartTime` or `EndTime`), so this may be dodgy to rely upon if that is the intent of the code.

Other than those issues, the call should work. Double check the access keys you are providing, the policies for the IAM user you are using, and as the comment from @krishna-kumar-r suggests, contact support in case your AWS account may be in arrears.